# New logo image for each refresh/page in Wordpress using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I have 5 different logo images, all same size, just different colors. I would like the images to rotate each time someone visits the website and the page reloads so they see a different color.

Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Michael Jones for the answer.
So where would I insert the php code? Into one of the files for the theme?
I prefer CSS because I can easily add it to the them and not worry about losing the code when updating things.

Comment: Thank you @essmahr for the answer. Same question I had as Michael.
Where would I insert the javascript code? Into one of the files for the theme? Would I then lose the custom edit if I update the theme?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a simple idea that would do this. Basically, generate a random number, and then depending on the number display a image. Therefore each time the page loads, there will be a new RANDOM image.

Here is an example piece of code:

```
<?php
$imagenum = rand(1,10);
if (($imagenum = 1) or ($imagenum = 2)) {
    //Display Image #1 Here
    echo "<img src=''>";
}
elseif (($imagenum = 3) or ($imagenum = 4)) {
    //Display Image #2 Here
    echo "<img src=''>";
}
elseif (($imagenum = 5) or ($imagenum = 6)) {
    //Display Image #3 Here
    echo "<img src=''>";
}
elseif (($imagenum = 7) or ($imagenum = 8)) {
    //Display Image #4 Here
    echo "<img src=''>";
}
else {
    //Display Image #5 Here
    echo "<img src=''>";
}
```

This way, it is ***ALWAYS*** be random which image the user gets.

---

**EDIT**

You asked if there was a way to do this in CSS. The answer is no, there is no way that CSS can do this. The reason why is CSS is not *dynamic*, it does what you tell it too, and it can not think (per say).

Answer (score 0):

How about a bit of Javascript?

```
function updateImgSrc() {
  var img = document.getElementById('my-logo');
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*5) + 1;
  img.src = img.src.slice(-5, img.src.length) + rand + ".jpg";

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  updateImgSrc();
});
```

...This means if you have an image with an id of `#my-logo`, on each page load it will update the image path to include a different (random) number, between 1 and 5, at the end of the filename. If you name your logos appropriately (logo-variation-1.jpg, logo-variation-2.jpg etc) you'll get a different image on each page load.

If you're including your logo with a css background image, you could just as easily have the javascript add a class to the element and then pull in an appropriate image from your stylesheet:

```
function updateImgClass() {
  var imgElement = $('my-logo');
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*5) + 1;
  imgElement.addClass('logo-' + rand);

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  updateImgClass();
});
```

css:

```
#my-logo.logo-1 {
  background-image: url('path-to/image-here.jpg')
}

#my-logo.logo-2 {
  background-image: url('path-to/image-here2.jpg')
}

.. et cetera
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code it will work Perfectly.

```
<?php
$imagenum = rand(1,3);
if (($imagenum == 1)) {
    //Display Image #1 Here
    echo "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/image.png'>";
}
elseif (($imagenum == 2)) {
    //Display Image #2 Here
    echo "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/image.png'>";
}
elseif (($imagenum == 3)) {
    //Display Image #3 Here
    echo "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/image.png'>";
}
else {
    //Display Image Here
    echo "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/image.png'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you'll store urls in array with number as key and get the url with number as array key will be more simple to handle things and it will reduce the duplicate echo and if check line.